# Converting a .asp form that sends email to WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm pretty new to WordPress and web development. I've been working on converting an older website to WordPress for a person I do business with. I've got almost everything done, but I'm having trouble getting his contact form to work properly. I've created a custom template for the page, but am not sure how to get the page for when the email is sent to work. My template code looks like this

```
<?php
/*Template Name: Contact*/
?>
<?php
get_header();
?>




<?php $nav = get_field ('navigation_links'); ?>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" onload="MM_preloadImages('<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s4.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s3.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s4.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s3.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s4.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s3.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s4.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s3.png');">

<div class = "container" style = "background-image:url(<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/Generic_Background.jpg);">
<div id="header" style="position:relative;">
  <div id="FWTableContainer1270816879">
    <table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">
      <!-- fwtable fwsrc="masthead.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="masthead.png" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "1270816879" fwnested="0" -->
      <tr>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="179" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="55" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="179" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="89" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="179" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="68" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="199" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="12" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><img name="masthead_r1_c1_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r1_c1_s1.png" width="960" height="193" border="0" id="masthead_r1_c1_s1" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="193" border="0" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $nav['home_link'];?>" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out');" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','masthead_r2_c1_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s4.png',1);" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar1','masthead_r2_c1_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s3.png',1);"><img name="masthead_r2_c1_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c1_s1.png" width="179" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c1_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><img name="masthead_r2_c2_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c2_s1.png" width="55" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c2_s1" alt="" /></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:;" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out');MM_menuStartTimeout(1000);" onmouseover="MM_menuShowMenu('MMMenuContainer1120175513_0', 'MMMenu1120175513_0',0,43,'masthead_r2_c3_s1');MM_nbGroup('over','masthead_r2_c3_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s4.png',1);" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar1','masthead_r2_c3_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s3.png',1);"><img name="masthead_r2_c3_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c3_s1.png" width="179" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c3_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><img name="masthead_r2_c4_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c4_s1.png" width="89" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c4_s1" alt="" /></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $nav['link_dealers'];?>" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out');" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','masthead_r2_c5_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s4.png',1);" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar1','masthead_r2_c5_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s3.png',1);"><img name="masthead_r2_c5_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c5_s1.png" width="179" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c5_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><img name="masthead_r2_c6_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c6_s1.png" width="68" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c6_s1" alt="" /></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $nav['link_contact'];?>" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out');" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','masthead_r2_c7_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s2.png','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s4.png',1);" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar1','masthead_r2_c7_s1','<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s3.png',1);"><img name="masthead_r2_c7_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c7_s1.png" width="199" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c7_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
        <td><img name="masthead_r2_c8_s1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/masthead_r2_c8_s1.png" width="12" height="43" border="0" id="masthead_r2_c8_s1" alt="" /></td>
        <td><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/menu_images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="43" border="0" alt="" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="MMMenuContainer1120175513_0">
      <div id="MMMenu1120175513_0" onmouseout="MM_menuStartTimeout(1000);" onmouseover="MM_menuResetTimeout();"> <a href="<?php echo $nav['link_pistols'];?>" id="MMMenu1120175513_0_Item_0" class="MMMIFVStyleMMMenu1120175513_0" onmouseover="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu1120175513_0');"> Pistols&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Knives </a> <a href="<?php echo $nav['link_rifles'];?>" id="MMMenu1120175513_0_Item_1" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu1120175513_0" onmouseover="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu1120175513_0');"> Rifles&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Shotguns </a> <a href="<?php echo $nav['link_collectibles'];?>" id="MMMenu1120175513_0_Item_2" class="MMMIVStyleMMMenu1120175513_0" onmouseover="MM_menuOverMenuItem('MMMenu1120175513_0');"> Collectibles&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Antiques </a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content"  style="position:relative;">
  <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="maincontent" --><div id="centertable"><center><table width="70%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  style="background-color:#fcb076;">
   <tr>
     <td align="center"><h2 style="margin-top:4px;">Contact Information</h2>        <h5>Phone: 574.295.6440<br />
       Monday – Friday 9:00 am – 5:00 pm        Eastern Standard Time</h5>
       <h5>Saturdays 9:00 am - noon<br />
         Fax: 574.522.1600 (Anytime)</h5></td>
     
     </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tr>
         <td align="center"><h5>Mailing Address:<br />
           22382 State Road 120 Elkhart, IN 46516</h5></td>
         <td align="center"><h5>Physical Address:<br />
           22382 State Road 120 Elkhart, IN 46516</h5></td>
         </tr>
       </table></td>
     
     </tr>
   <tr>
     <td align="center"><h5>E-mail - <a href="mailto:paul.stybert@gmail.com">paul.stybert@gmail.com</a></h5></td>
     
     </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><h5>If you have questions, you can reach us by phone, fax, regular mail, or use the email form below. This form will be sent to a customer service representative, who will be in contact with you soon. Thank you for your interest in Doug's Guns.</h5></td>
     
     </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:#005d90;color:#fff;">
     <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000;"><h3>Online Information Request Form</h3></td>
     </tr>
   <tr >
     <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #000;background-color:#d3a06f;"><form action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/template-emailproc.php" method="post" id="mailform" name="mailform">
 <input type="hidden" value="yxstreme" name="name"  />    
     <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="formtable" style="margin-top:0px;">
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">*Name</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield1">
         <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" />
         <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldMinCharsMsg">Minimum number of characters not met.</span><span class="textfieldMaxCharsMsg">Exceeded maximum number of characters.</span></span></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">*Email</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><span id="sprytextfield2">
         <input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" />
         <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Company</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtCompany"></label>
           <input type="text" name="txtCompany" id="txtCompany" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Address</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtAddress"></label>
           <input type="text" name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">City</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtCity"></label>
           <input type="text" name="txtCity" id="txtCity" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">State</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtState"></label>
           <input type="text" name="txtState" id="txtState" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Postal Code</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtPostalCode"></label>
           <input type="text" name="txtPostalCode" id="txtPostalCode" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Phone</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtPhone"></label>
           <input type="text" name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Interested In:</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><select name="ddInterest" class="contactformoption" id="ddInterest">
           <option value="null" selected="selected">Please Choose One</option>
           <option value="Buying One Of Our Products">Buying One Of Our Products</option>
           <option value="Pistols">Pistols</option>
           <option value="Rifles or Shotguns">Rifles or Shotguns</option>
           <option value="Collectibles">Collectibles</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option></select></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">How did you find our website?</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top">
           <input type="text" name="txtHowFind" id="txtHowFind" /></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">Comments/Questions</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><label for="txtComment"></label>
           <textarea name="txtComments" id="txtComment" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea></td>
         </tr>
       <tr>
         <td align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
         <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Send" /></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       
       </form>
  </td>
     </tr>
   </table></center>
</div>
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
<?php wp_footer();?>

<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

I know it has something to do with the post method and where the email is being sent  I changed the link to a page I've created with a custom template.  The code that is different in that template is

```
<div class="content" id="maincontent"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="MainContent" -->
<%  
on error resume next

xname=request.form("txtName")
xemail=request.form("txtEmail")
xcompany=request.form("txtCompany")
xaddress=request.form("txtAddress")
xcity=request.form("txtCity")
xstate=request.form("txtState")
xpostalcode=request.form("txtPostalCode")
xphone=request.form("txtPhone")
xinterest=request.form("ddInterest")
xhowfind=request.form("txtHowFind")
xcomments=request.form("txtComments")

If Request.form("name") = "yxstreme" Then 
    psFrom="no-reply@plugguardstore.com"
    psSubject="Contact from Doug's Guns Website"

   ' message body
   psbody = "<html><head><title>E-mail sent from the Doug's Guns website</title></head>"
   
   psBody="<body><h5>The following e-mail was sent from the Doug's Guns website :</h5>"
   psBody=psBody & "<hr />"
   psBody=psBody & "<p>Name: " & xname & "</p>"
   psBody=psBody & "<p>Email" & xemail & "<br />Company: " & xcompany & "<br />Address: " & xaddress & "<br />"
   psBody=psBody & "City: " & xcity & "<br />State: " & xstate & "<br />Postal Code: " & xpostalcode & "<br />"
   psBody=psBody & "Phone: " & xphone & "<br />"
   psBody=psBody & "Interested In: " & xinterest & "<br /><br />"
   psBody=psBody & "Discovered Website How: " & xhowfind & "<br /><br />"
   psBody=psBody & "Comment/question:<br />" & xcomments & "<br /><br />"

   psBody=psBody & "</body></html>"

   strErr = ""
   bSuccess = False
   'On Error Resume Next 
   'sendCDOHTMLEmail "paul.stybert@gmail.com",psFrom,psSubject,psBody
   sendCDOHTMLEmail "paul.stybert@gmail.com.com",psFrom,psSubject,psBody
   'sendCDONTSHTMLEmail "paul.stybert@gmail.com",psFrom,psSubject,psBody,1
   
   If Err <> 0 Then ' error occurred
     strErr = Err.Description 
     response.write "<center><h3>There was a problem sending your message.</h3></center>"
     'response.write Err.Description
   else
      bSuccess = True
      response.write "<center><h3>Thanks! Someone will be in touch with you shortly.</h3></center>"
   End If
End If


%>
  
  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --><!-- end .content --></div>
```

I'm lost on what I need to do to make this work. Any help would be appreciated. For your information the website was originally created with DreamWeaver and I've been moving the html code over and adding php for WordPress into it.

Comment: This is a simple form, find some plugin for WordPress for creating forms an re-create it manually.

Comment: That code looks like some form of VB

Comment: I avoid plugins for Wordpress where possible, but like @biesior a contact forms is one time I would actually recommend using one - apart from the simple interface, a good plugin can handle the validation and anti-spam features for you which are crucial these days.

Comment: @GetSet that's because ASP is based on VB...

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to ditch the asp processing for a Wordpress solution?

Apart from the good suggestion that @biesior [gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764189/converting-a-asp-form-that-sends-email-to-wordpress#comment110991878_62764189) about a form plugin (ninja forms, gravity forms), this would in your case be done by leaving the action part of the form empty (the form will then post to the same page) and handling the post variables and mailing in your template, just above the get_header(). You would also need to put conditions around the form content like this: `if (!isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]) { ... }`, so that it doesn't show if the form has been posted.

Look into the [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) function. And put a [nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/) in that form and probably a [(re)captcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html).

But, forms are nasty and a lot of work, so look into one of the popular form plugins. You'll set this one up in no-time